# Return statement in file doesn't stops class definition?

Tags: php, include, return

As stated here [php.net/return](http://php.net/return), there is an option to stop executing include with 'return' statement.

Who can tell me why this works as stated below

// test1.php

```
include 'test2.php';
var_dump(class_exists('TestClass_ShouldntBeDefined'));
```

// test2.php

```
return;
class TestClass_ShouldntBeDefined { }
```

// run

```
$ php -f test1.php
bool(true)
```

Why this is true?

When test2.php is changed to any other form of code execute (`if(true) { ... }`)

```
return;
{
    class TestClass_ShouldntBeDefined { }
}
```

then it works as expected

```
$ php -f test1.php
bool(false)
```

PHP version

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.4.7 (cli) (built: Sep 13 2012 04:20:14) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Return ends execution, but does not stop the include.

In the first case, the file is included, and execution stops after the return and control is given back to `test1.php`. But the class is included, and therefore class_exists returns `true`. So case 1 works as expected.

In the second case, by using the curly braces, the class definition becomes part of the execution. The return ends execution of the include, before the class is defined.

Comment: +1 for the _serial down voter_ ! (and of course the correct answer)

Comment: What did you mean writing "but not created"? It would be "created" withouth `return` statement? I thought class may be defined or not, and object creation is different thing. Your answer is pretty well and explained me what i've suspected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Adam I meant instantiated. But you are right, that part is unclear. I removed it.

Comment: @JvdBerg Do you have a reference to the PHP manual regarding this behaviour?

Comment: @JvdBerg - Thanks.  That page just says that script execution ends when return is used in the global scope; it says nothing specific about class declarations still being parsed.  Is that anywhere in the manual that you know of? I have looked for something more specific but haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Think of what php does when including a file: step 1 is to compile the include, step 2 is execute the code. The manual says it stops execution, but the compile is then already done.

Answer (score 2):

Classes and functions are not a part of sequential execution of the script. the return statement only ends the sequential execution not the oop execution.

Comment: Thanks for such fast response and short explanation!